# How to create a 'matrix' of objects such as arrays/list in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix, irb

I am now using `Ruby`, and come from a `MATLAB` background. I want to create a matrix of objects to be able to perform a matrix/mathematical style of indexing the elements as in MATLAB (mat(ii,jj) = *some cell object*). I do not see a similar matrix type object in Ruby.

- What I see is that the best option is to create a multidimensional array to give the structure of a matrix, is this correct?
- How to best create the matrix like structure in Ruby?
- Will the row and column size be defined from the initialization point and can those be changed afterwards?

Currently, I specifically want to insert other array objects in the elements of this matrix-like structure and do: (`ar=Array.new(3){Array.new(3)}`)

```
irb(main):001:0> ar=Array.new(3){Array.new(3)}
=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
irb(main):002:0> ar.size
=> 3
irb(main):004:0> ar[0].size
=> 3
irb(main):005:0> ar[0][0].size
NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):5
from :0
irb(main):006:0> ar[0][0]=[rand,rand,rand]
=> [0.327998120619301, 0.233951721107845, 0.0593579127810733]
irb(main):007:0> ar[1][0]=[rand,rand,rand]
=> [0.698779972364559, 0.290838119763321, 0.41685249594095]
irb(main):008:0> ar[2][0]=[rand,rand,rand]
```

and continue to fill the ^matrix^ this way. Is there a better way to do this?

but there is still the problem that I cannot perform operations easily such as:

```
irb(main):026:0> ar[0][0]
=> [0.327998120619301, 0.233951721107845, 0.0593579127810733]
irb(main):027:0> ar[0][1]
=> [0.360152144966612, 0.611276758393565, 0.0717397147786591]
irb(main):028:0> ar[0][0]-ar[0][1]
=> [0.327998120619301, 0.233951721107845, 0.0593579127810733]
```

so the only way I see is from individual indexing:

```
irb(main):032:0> ar[0][0][0]-ar[0][0][1]
=> 0.094046399511456
```

Comment: This would be easier to read without the IRB prompts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Matrix class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html):

```
require 'matrix'

m = Matrix[[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,1]]
m.det          #=> -1
m.diagonal?    #=> false
m.trace        #=> 1
```

You can easily create random matrix with:

```
m = Matrix.build(3,3) { rand }
```

NOTE: matrix is only able to serve 2d matrices, if you need more dimensions, you will need to build it by yourself.

Comment: It kind of is, however if you need to, you can still update it with `m.send(:[]=, x,y, value)`, it is not recommended though.